# uploading images/audio from iPhone to server not able to send big images

Tags: .net, iphone, objective-c, image, iis

I dont know if it is a problem with my iPhone code or SERVER.

I am uploading Image/Audio from iPhone to server using NSURLConnection. The images and audio get uploaded just fine if their size is less than 60KB.

If it is more than 60KB, I get a 400 Bad Request response from the server. 
I am not sure whats happening. I am clueless can someone help me

My webserver is IIS running on Windows 2008 R2. Web service is developed in .NET

Regards

Comment: You should check your server. My iPhone app usually uploaded to imageshack more than 60 KB and it works just fine

Comment: Here is a simple test to help determine if this is your app or the server: write a basic HTML form that creates an image upload to your server's upload api endpoint, and using the HTML form attach a larger image. If the request fails in the same way, you have some certainty that this is irrelevant to your iPhone app. But make sure you've done a good job at creating an identical HTTP request with the form :)

Answer (score 0):

sounds like just one chunk of data is send.

I am using [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest) for receiving/sending data.

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request addPostValue:@"Ben" forKey:@"names"];
[request addPostValue:@"George" forKey:@"names"];
[request addFile:@"/Users/ben/Desktop/ben.jpg" forKey:@"photos"];
[request addData:imageData withFileName:@"george.jpg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"photos"];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a server issue as I can upload videos of a 3.5 MB limit on the .NET server.

Comment: Perhaps this should be a comment instead? Also I am doubting how much help this could provide considering it is a rather specific question and it is from 2 years ago.