# iphone SDK : Upload image from iphone to a php Server send empty file ?(sample code link inside)

Tags: php, iphone, upload, sdk, nsdata

I try to send a photo and GPS location to server via PHP

here is the PHP part:[Copy from here](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_file_upload.asp)
Saving the Uploaded File

The examples above create a temporary copy of the uploaded files in the PHP temp folder on the server.

The temporary copied files disappears when the script ends. To store the uploaded file we need to copy it to a different location:

```
<?php
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

The script above checks if the file already exists, if it does not, it copies the file to the specified folder.

Note: This example saves the file to a new folder called "upload"

now back to iOS part ,I only can send GPS location to server ,it's easy because just a string.

and you can [download sample code here](http://www.sendspace.com/file/cnaeh1)

But an image is not,I do some search and found this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939335/upload-image-from-iphone-to-the-server-folder)

I directly put the code in my send GPS&image button

the best thing is it can feedback I send the file success or failed

this is the most message I got after I send photo to server

**1.Invalid file**

**2.Return Code: 
Upload: 
Type: 
Size: 0 Kb
Temp file: 
Stored in: upload/**

I follow some guide to save image to NSData

```
NSData *photoData= UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.theimageView.image, 1.0);
```

and I also check there is data inside or not

so simply add this code into Button action

```
if (photoData == nil) {
    NSLog(@"The photo is nothing !!!");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Photo inside !!!!");
```

It works fine.......

**But How To Upload An Image To Server ???**

**maybe I need to give a file name then upload it ???**

but  how to...

I never use camera function and upload data before

Hope someone can figure out this problem

**Many Great Thanks !!!**

Comment: I had a similar error when using a HTML form instead of an iPhone. Have you significantly tested the Upload Script so that you can be sure that there's no error here?

Comment: sorry I don't know the PHP or HTML part , that's my another friend writes........sorry this no help to your question,But I think I just send a empty file to PHP server.But after I snap a photo I get a message "ERROR: FigCreateCGImageFromJPEG returned -12905. Input (null) was 630283 bytes."

Comment: so...It should be something in my NSData

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642975/uploading-images-audio-from-iphone-to-server-not-able-to-send-big-images

Comment: I'm not sure this link help or not ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use HTTP multipart POST or ASIHTTPRequest

---

```
@WebberLai

Save the image to home directory:
 NSString  *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/image.jpg"];
    UIImage *img = pickerImage;


// Write a UIImage to JPEG with minimum compression (best quality) 
    [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.5) writeToFile:jpgPath atomically:YES];

    NSString *photoPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/image.jpg"];

    request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:webServiceUrl];
    [request setPostValue:requestString forKey:@"data"];
    [request setFile:photoPath forKey:@"apiupload"];
    [request startSynchronous];
```

Comment: How do I know where I save the data and the what's the file name ?or path ...I have know idea anything about the data info ,but thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

It's fine to add this

```
NSString *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/image.jpg"]; UIImage *img = pickerImage;

[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.5) writeToFile:jpgPath atomically:YES];
```

But When I try to put in my button action

```
NSString *photoPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/image.jpg"];

request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:webServiceUrl];
[request setPostValue:requestString forKey:@"data"];
[request setFile:photoPath forKey:@"apiupload"];
[request startSynchronous];
```

It got many error message ,I think is delegate problem

first complier says "request undeclared"  and "ASIFormDataRequest undeclared"

and "requestString undeclared"

I try to give request and requestString declared

So I use `ASIFormDataRequest *request;` and `NSString *requestString;`

It clear an error about "equestString undeclared"

I don't know how to declared ASIFormDataRequest so it still a error...

Did I right to put this in IBAction ???

I look some example [here](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use)

Thanks again~you are a really nice guy !

More Edit :

OK, Here is more step about how to import necessary .h .m  and framework

[download here](http://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/tarball/master)

and import this header :

```
ASIHTTPRequestConfig.h

ASIHTTPRequestDelegate.h

ASIProgressDelegate.h

ASICacheDelegate.h

ASIInputStream.h

ASIInputStream.m

ASIHTTPRequest.h

ASIHTTPRequest.m

ASIFormDataRequest.h

ASIFormDataRequest.m

ASINetworkQueue.h

ASINetworkQueue.m

ASIDownloadCache.h

ASIDownloadCache.m
```

iPhone projects must also include:

```
ASIAuthenticationDialog.h

ASIAuthenticationDialog.m

Reachability.h (in the External/Reachability folder)

Reachability.m (in the External/Reachability folder)
```

---

than import Framework:

***CFNetwork***

***SystemConfiguration.framework***

***MobileCoreServices.framework***

***CoreGraphics.framework***

***libz.1.2.3.dylib***

Answer (score 0):

OK,Here is a small bug between iPhone3 & iPhone4/touch4

@ dhil's Answer is almost right , You just need to give a right key (depends on Server)

```
[request setPostValue:requestString forKey:@"data"];
[request setFile:photoPath forKey:@"apiupload"];
```

Ok...now if you use iPhone3 , and you don't give `requestString` **alloc**

It runs fine ~

But if you run on iPhone4/touch4  ,It will cause **EXC_BAD_ACCESS**

even both device is iOS 4.1

So...Hope this answer will help you to save time about upload image to server.