# SnapChat User Posting and Retrieval

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Im working on an iOS app that the user can post then receive their snapchats. I have seen this done with ["SnapHack"](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/snap-hack-pro-for-snapchat/id716560946?mt=8) but SnapChat itself does not have an Api that allows you to do those things. So could someone lead me in the right direction to be able to do this?

Comment: Do you want to build like application or you have any specific situation?

Comment: I mainly want to know how to send a picture. @Retro

Answer (score 1):

I would have commented, but don't have enough reputation (just yet).

Firstly I'd like to say that Snapchat does have an API but it is against their Terms and Conditions to reverse engineer their application etc.

Before you start building your application you should read up on the **[Snapchat API](http://gibsonsec.org/snapchat/fulldisclosure/)** to see how it works.

Once you know how to use the API you will then be able to create your iOS app for sending and receiving Snaps.

Answer (score 0):

For uploading image you need a web server and any server side scripting knowledge so that you can upload your image from IPhone to server but there are several help for achieving this

[upload image from iphone to the server folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939335/upload-image-from-iphone-to-the-server-folder)

[iphone SDK : Upload image from iphone to a php Server send empty file ?(sample code link inside)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985515/iphone-sdk-upload-image-from-iphone-to-a-php-server-send-empty-file-sample-c)

look here and come with more specific problem set :)

Comment: If you want to avoid server scripting, try using Windows Azure. You can upload and download images to/from server using Objective C. Microsoft has created frameworks to achieve this.